# Adding starting splashing Animation to Google workspace Add -on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons, google-workflows

I'm creating a google workspace add-on to a organization.For styling purpose I want to add starting splash animation very similler to the Google map, keep and contact Add-on have.Can I get an idea about, that can be done to the third party add-on , that we are creating ?

Comment: When you mention Workspace add-on, you are referring to actual [Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-workspace-addons) or [editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons)? What you are asking for is not possible in Workspace add-ons, but it probably is for editor add-ons, which allow for custom HTML.

Comment: I ask for workspace add-on. I got my answer. Thank you Iamblichus.

Answer (score 3):

Google Workspace add-on are pretty limited in terms of design you can do. And you won't be able - as of writing - to create a splash screen that disappear without user's interaction.

You can ask for such feature using Google's [feedback form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).